# How to use insertRowsAtIndexPath() with multiple custom prototype cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have the following setup in my `UITableView`:

- Prototype Cell 1 = always visible, has 1 row that contains a `UITextField` (of which the input will make the other cells appear/disappear) and some labels.
- Prototype Cell 2 = appears based on input, 1 row with an image from object
- Prototype Cell 3 = appears based on input, 1 row with a label from object
- Prototype Cell 4 = appears based on input, # of rows based on array in object

So I have an object that contains an image (for single row in cell 2), name (for single row in cell 3) and array (for the multiple rows in cell 4).

Based on the input in prototype cell 1, I need to populate and show cell 2, 3 and 4. All of the data in these new cells comes from that one object that was decided by entering something in the `UITextfield` from the first cell.

But I can't seem to figure out where and how to implement the following method to create the new rows/cells:

```
tableView?.insertRows(at:[IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

I would need to use it to insert 1 row in prototype cell 2, to insert 1 row in prototype cell 3 and multiple rows in prototype cell 4.

And help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are supposed add your logic for prototype cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `inserRows()` is not the best way to do that.

You can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and you need to update data you can reload all table with `reloadData()` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,  
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        if indexPath.row == 1 { 
            var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1 ") as YourTableViewCell
        return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2 { 
            var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2 ") as YourTableViewCell
         return cell
        }
        //do this to maintain the same cells at position 1..4 and for the rest of the rows
        else {
           var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell5 ") as YourTableViewCell
           return cell
        }

    }
```

Comment: The reason why I would like to try the insertRows() function is because I need the 3 new cells to animate. Using reloadData() would then wrongly refresh the first (always visible) cell as well. While reloadRowsAtIndexPaths() gave me an unspecified error.
I'm also confused with where I would set the actual data that goes into the cells...
I explained the complete problem in more detail here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259423/swift-how-to-animate-show-hide-cells-based-on-uitextfield-input-by-reloading)

Comment: You could try change the UITableViewController and put a UIView in the place of the first row, and the other rows will be inside the UITableView and instead of use heightForRowAt to hide and show cells, use flags inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath to show the correct cell and use reloadData()